# Non Locally Compact Space at every point implies Anticompact

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $\textbf{(X, $\cal T$)}$, which for convinience we further suposse is Haussdorf. Any finite subset in any given topological space is of course compact. If the space is non locally compact $\textbf{at every point}$, then for any point in our space we can't find a compact neighborhood (in a Haussdorf space this is equivalent to the non existence of a compact basis of neighborhoods for that point). Want can be then told about compact sets of the space? The Sorgenfrey line, for example, is a non locally compact space whose only compact sets are the countable ones. I was wondering if this could be generalized for any topological space satisfying the previous conditions, although I'm aware it could be a very restrictive assertion.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: A space can be non-locally compact simply because it fails to be locally compact at *one* point. Being non-locally compact at *every* point is a much stronger condition; is that what you meant?

Comment: That's true, let me edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately from the definition, we have that a space $X$ is nowhere locally compact (that is, not locally compact at any point) if and only if there are no compact neighborhoods of any point. In other words, compact subsets of $X$ do not contain any open subsets of $X$.

I'm not sure what more can be said in general; there's a huge variety of non-locally compact spaces. For example, let $X$ be the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Then $X$ is nowhere locally compact, and every compact manifold embeds as a closed subspace of $X$. As you can see, this condition of being nowhere locally compact doesn't really restrict which compact spaces can occur as *closed* subsets.